# Python importing variables from other file

Tags: python, function, file, variables, import

I have 3 files in the same directory : test1.py , test2.py and **init**.py.

In test1.py I have this code:

```
def test_function():
    a = "aaa"
```

In test2.py I have this code:

```
from test1 import *


def test_function2():
    print(a)


test_function2()
```

I can import "test_function" (and call the function) into test2.py but i cannot use the variable "a" in test2.py .

> Error : Unresolved reference "a" .

I would like to know if it possible to use "a" inside test2.py .

Comment: I tried making the variable "a" global in "test_function" but it didn't work , I tried making it global in "test_function2" but it said variable not defined at module level.

Comment: *test1.py* is invalid (you wanted the 2nd line indented)?

Comment: sorry mistake when pasting code

Answer (score 3):

In test1.py you could have a function that returns the value of the variable a

```py
def get_a():
    return a
```

And when you're in test2.py you can call `get_a()`.

So in test2.py do this to essentially move over the value of a from test1.py.

```
from test1 import *

a = get_a()

def test_function2():
    print(a)


test_function2()
```

Comment: That won't help.I need a solution inside one of these functions

Answer (score 1):

[What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?¶](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. **If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.**

So make the variable `a` global and call `test_function()` in `test1` module so that it makes `a` as global variable while loading modules

**test1.py**

```
def test_function():
  global a
  a = "aaa"

test_function()
```

**test2.py**

```
from test1 import *

def test_function2():
  print(a)


test_function2()
```

Answer (score 1):

Test1.py

```
def test_function():
    a = "aaa"
    return a
```

Test2.py

```
import test1


def test_function2():
    print(test1.test_function())


test_function2()
```

Comment: I didn't explain myself well , test_function should only have the variable "a" and do nothing (not return a in this example)

Answer (score 1):

`a` is only defined in the scope of `test_function()`. You must define it outside the function and access it using the `global` keyword. This is what it looks like:

**test1.py**

```
a = ""
def test_function():
    global a
    a = "aaa"
```

**test2.py**

```
import test1

def test_function2():
    print(test1.a)

test1.test_function()
test_function2()
```

Answer (score 0):

test1.py's code will be this.

```
def H():
    global a
    a = "aaa"
H()
```

and test2.py's code will be this.

```
import test1 as o
global a
o.H()
print(o.a)
```

This will allow you to call test one H

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfect (with 'a' defined outside out the test1_function), was able to print 'a'. So try the following :
1. Make sure it is a global variable in test1.
2. Import test1 in an interactive session and find out the bug.
3. Double check the environment setup.

Thanks !
:)

Comment: @redhunter,if you don't want a return function, you can then make a class and add 'a' inside it and refer it in test2, but its like 'burning the house to kill a cockroach'