# define a variable used in a function in another file python

Tags: python

I have two files and for some reason I do not want to define my variable as an input in my function:

function.py

```
def test():
   print(var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   var = "test"
   test()
```

call_function.py

```
from function import *
global var 
var = "test"
test()
```

If I do this i get an error saying that var is not defined. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python importing variables from other file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517260/python-importing-variables-from-other-file)

Comment: You could also remove "if __name__ == '__main__'", as this line prevents the code below it from executing when you import the file instead of running it directly

Comment: "for some reason I do not want to define my variable as an input in my function" do you really need this?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at what is a function scope, here is a useful link:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but the fact that this works does not mean that it is a good thing to do, DO NOT CODE LIKE THIS.

```
from function import *

var = ['I WILL FIRE YOU IF I SEE CODE LIKE THIS IN AN APPLICATION']

test.__globals__['var'] = var

test() # output: ['I WILL FIRE YOU IF I SEE CODE LIKE THIS IN AN APPLICATION']

var[0] = "DO NOT DO THIS, YOU'LL BREAK SOMETHING IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT ARE YOU DOING"

test() # output: ["DO NOT DO THIS, YOU'LL BREAK SOMETHING IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT ARE YOU DOING"]
```